# What is the best treatment which has actually worked for alopecia aerata

Tags: alopecia

I have seen lots of youtube videos which has confused me a lot and it looks like all of them are lying, I have not seen anybody before and after the experience.

What is the best treatment which has actually worked for alopecia aerate

Answer (score 2):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alopecia_areata#Treatment) suggests that there are no known reliable and safe treatments. Corticosteroids have been used but evidence for efficacy is weak. The US FDA [has allowed breakthrough use of at least one drug](https://investor.lilly.com/news-releases/news-release-details/lilly-receives-fda-breakthrough-therapy-designation-baricitinib) that is ordinarily prescribed for rheumatoid arthritis following early trial successes, with a [phase 3 trial ongoing](https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/NCT03899259), but there is no FDA-approved treatment.

In general as a rule there is a lot more financial (and other) incentive to say there is a magic cure for something, and almost no incentive to say there is not. Even if someone provides before and after "evidence", this is not reliable unless it is coming from a reputable source (such as a scientific article in a reputable journal, a trusted government regulatory agency or public health institute, etc). For a simple example, you could take an "after" photo, remove some hair and take a "before" photo, and claim whatever treatment you want worked.